# Set a token per item in a Splunk multiselect

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I would like to set a boolean token (selected/not selected) for every item in a multiselect input on a form. I saw a workaround for the (bizarre?) lack of out-of-the-box ability to do something like this:
https://community.splunk.com/t5/Dashboards-Visualizations/Hide-Display-Panels-Using-Multiselect/m-p/336502/highlight/true#M21830

I believe a reasonable simplification is:

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="multiselect" token="item_selector" searchWhenChanged="true">
    <delimiter>,</delimiter>
    <choice value="item1">item1</choice>
    <choice value="item2">item2</choice>
  </input>
</fieldset>

<search>
  <query>
   eval data="$item_selector$"
   | eval show1=match(data,"item1")
   | eval show2=match(data,"item2")
  </query>
  <done>
    <condition>
      <set token="show1_token">$result.show1$</set>
      <set token="show2_token">$result.show2$</set>
    </condition>
   </done>
 </search>
```

I don't believe this is working, as:

```
  <row>
    <panel depends="$my_true$">
      <title>Panel 1</title>
      <html>$show1_token$</html>
      <html>$show1_token$</html>
    </panel>
  </row>
```

simply displays the following on the dashboard no matter which items are selected in the multiselect:

> $show1_token$

> $show2_token$

whereas I would have expected some combination of "true" or "false" (depending on which items were selected).

They called this a "dummy search" - when would this search be executed?

Is this a reasonable way (if it can be corrected) to set a boolean token per item? Is there an alternative (other than javascript, as I don't have permissions for that on this dashboard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes to the dashboard XML to fix the problems you're experiencing in the Display panel and now it correctly shows the token value when you change your selection in the `multiselect` input. Give it a shot.

```
<dashboard>
  <label>Multiselect - Token Test</label>
  <fieldset>
    <input type="multiselect" token="item_selector" searchWhenChanged="true">
      <delimiter>,</delimiter>
      <choice value="item1">item1</choice>
      <choice value="item2">item2</choice>
    </input>
  </fieldset>
<search>
  <query>
   | makeresults
   | eval data="$item_selector$"
   | eval show1=toString(match(data,"item1"))
   | eval show2=toString(match(data,"item2"))
  </query>
  <done>
   <condition>
    <set token="show1_token">$result.show1$</set>
    <set token="show2_token">$result.show2$</set>
   </condition>
  </done>
 </search>
<row>
  <panel depends="$item_selector$">
  <title>Panel 1</title>
  <html>$show1_token$</html>
  <html>$show2_token$</html>
  </panel>
 </row>
</dashboard>
```

The search (dummy search) will be executed as soon as the user selects an option from the `multiselect` dropdown.

There was an issue in the `eval` statement because - "Fields cannot be assigned a boolean result".
That's the reason I converted the boolean from `match` function to string